# asp.net-mvc shared menu code in table

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a page where the left hand side is a list of bulleted items and the right hand side the actual page of the selected item on the left.

right now i am using a table to split the two sections.

i have a seperate page for each link but i want to avoid repeating the left hand side menu code in every page so there is only one place to change it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a m[aster view page](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-12-cs.aspx) and put all repeating codes (ie menu) in the master.